# exportar importar banco oracle 11g sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle11g, sqldeveloper

A questão é a seguinte, eu tenho uma base de dados local, onde já tenho a estrutura e dados nas respectivas tabelas que preciso. Estou querendo exportar essa base de dados para outra máquina, exatamente com a mesma estrutura, ou seja tudo que esta na minha conexão local, queria exportar para uma outra máquina, criando um repositório local, alguém poderia me ajudar ??
Uso o sqldeveloper 11g segue a imagem com a estrutura que quero exportar..!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Observação:**
>   Antes de tudo, recomendo que realize um teste em 2 bancos para ver se
>   o resultado esperado atende ao seu problema.

Você pode utilizar o recurso, de **Assistente de Cópia de Banco de Dados**, disponível no menu:

```
Ferramentas > Cópia de Banco de Dados
```

Na primeira etapa selecione a origem e destino e as opções que mais lhe fizerem sentido, selecionei "Substituir objetos de destino existentes",e "Truncar destino antes de copiar", para limpar tudo antes de fazer a copia:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na segunda etapa, os tipos de objetos, nesse caso deixei marcado todos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então especifique todos os objetos, clicando em <kbd>pesquisar</kbd>,e depois em <kbd>>></kbd>
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser você pode especificar alguns dados, não fiz nada nessa etapa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois Finalizar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ira processar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gerar um log com a copia:

```
Opção de Cópia: Cópia de Objetos
Conexão de Origem: teste1
Conexão de Destino: teste2
Objetos DDL:
Views
Tudo Views
Tipos
Tudo Tipos
Links de Banco de Dados
Tudo Links de Banco de Dados
Tabelas
TESTE1.TABLE1
Sequências
Tudo Sequências
Views Materializadas
Tudo Views Materializadas
Índices
TESTE1.H_ID
Triggers
Todos Triggers para TESTE1.TABLE1
Logs de Views Materializadas
Tudo Logs de Views Materializadas
Procedures
Tudo Procedures
Pacotes
Tudo Pacotes
Corpos de Packages
Tudo Corpos de Packages
Funções
Tudo Funções
Objetos de Dados:
Tabelas
TABLE1
Copiar DDL: Sim
Substituir
Copiar Dados: Sim
--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
  DROP TABLE "TABLE1" cascade constraints;


Table "TABLE1" eliminado.


--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
set define off;

--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table TABLE1
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "TABLE1" ("NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ID" NUMBER, "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), "COLUMN3" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "TESTE1_INDEX" ;

Table "TABLE1" criado.


--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------


--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
  TRUNCATE TABLE "TABLE1";


Table "TABLE1" truncado.


--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
Movendo Dados do objeto TABLE1

Inserir 10.000 linhas em TABLE1 em 2.321 milissegundos
--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
set define off;

--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index H_ID
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE INDEX "H_ID" ON "TABLE1" ("ID") PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "TESTE1_INDEX" ;

Index "H_ID" criado.


set define off;

set define off;

--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------


--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Um detalhe, que talvez não faça diferença, para você é que ele utiliza a mesma `tablespace` da origem, não da para trocar, mesmo se você setar anteriormente que o usuário utilizará tal `tablespace`, o destino ficara com a mesma `tablespace` da origem.

Comment: Uma pergunta, eu fiz o procedimento, mas com esse procedimento, eu faça a cópia  do banco para o mesmo computador, eu preciso copiar em outra máquina essa repositório.

Comment: E se voc~e criar uma conexão na sua máquina acessando a outra máquina ? ou seja, acessar o banco da outra máquina pela sua

Comment: Não consegui copiar o banco conectando a outra máquina, contudo vi que ao copiar o panco ele gera um arquivo dentro da pasto do oracle, foi ae que vi que vi que tinha como usar o data pump, pegar o arquivo e copiar em outra máquina, desta forma resolveu, mas muito obrigado pelas dicas, ajudou bastante, e pra copiar pra outra conexão funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Eu particularmente gosto de sempre fazer via datapump, vejo acontecendo, fico mais tranquilo kkk :) abraço